# PHP Database configuration error

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to establish connection with database but I am getting warning " Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\ideal\admin\config.php on line 7" . I have checked it few times and made it sure that I am using mysqli and not mysql.

Here is my config.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "******";
$mysql_database = "database";
$dbase = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect  to database");
mysqli_select_db($dbase,$mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
mysqli_query($dbase,"set time_zone='+05:30'");

if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_id']))
header("Location:index.php");
```

?>

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: Do you have a line in your php.ini file for php_mysqli? Is it commented or not?

Comment: This code **should not** produce this particular warning. We cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: @mishu I am using mysqli_* in other files. No issues happening in those files.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use

```
mysqli_select_db($dbase,$mysql_database) or die("Could not select database");
```

pass db name into

```
$dbase = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database) or die("Could not connect  to database");
```

Comment: Thanks for info... However warning still persists..

Comment: also change query to mysqli_query("set time_zone='+05:30'");. It's working fine here. warning is not an error ,it can execute your code

Comment: Yes warning is not an error. Its working fine but why this warning? Thanks.

Comment: working now? pl tick correct to accept answer

Comment: :P not now. It was working earlier also . I just want to get rid of this warning. I know it should't happen normally. If in case you can suggest me reasons then this answer will surely be marked as accepted. :D

Comment: you mean Deprecated: mysql_connect() warning?

Comment: yes.Since I have used mysqli_* and stil getting this warning.

Comment: okay. Pl add this code into one new file. just this code only and check

Comment: working on new file or still get error?

Comment: means same warning on new page also?

Answer (score 1):

I check your code in our localhost.Everything in your code is right but need to check privilege of username and password is set or not in database.if privilege is not set in database then you can use username is root and password is blank and then check code is definitely work without error.